# How to Make View Animate Like Crumpling Paper

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, animation

On click of button I want to give animation on view like crumpling paper and put in right-bottom corner of view, please give me any solution to complete this task also you can see this link for crumpling effect.

http://vimeo.com/2243632

Comment: that doesn't look as much like paper as it does a towel or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard methods for solute it in Xcode.

Take complete solution: https://github.com/melfar/crumpledpaper